# It is + adjective + wh clause

Tags: adjectives, subordinate-clauses, extraposition

> It is funny how you say that.
>   It is amazing what you did.
>    It
>   is terrible why it happened.

Those sentences have same structure: It is + adjective + wh clause.

My question is, is it always possible to use this sentence structure with ANY adjective? I sometimes find this sentence hard to use with some adjectives like "happy".

Also, please tell me the name of this sentence. It would help me greatly. Thank you.

Comment: Dear close voter, could you please **stop**?! This is starting to get really annoying. On another note, this is a very interesting question. **What adjectives can't fit in that construction?**

Comment: None of those three sentences sound natural to me - they are all just slightly off, and seem to toe the line between two different meanings in each case. `1` _It is funny **that** you say that_ or _. **How** you say that is funny._  `2`  _. **What** you did is amazing._ or _It is amazing **that** you did that._  `3` _. **How** it happened is terrible._ or _It is terrible **that** it happened._

Comment: All three example adjectives describe the speaker's emotional reaction to <the wh clause>.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to think of adjectives that wouldn't work here. Using the adjective "furry" or another adjective describing a physical trait struggles to work in your case.

The closest I can come to using furry in a sentence like yours is below, but it doesn't look like it works.

> It is furry what you made your dog.

Answer (score 0):

They all are correct.

Consider the following sentences -

> 1. How you say that is funny.
> 2. What you did is amazing.
> 3. What happened is terrible.

These sentences make sense and indeed correct.

Consider sentence #2

> **What you did** is amazing.

The bold part - *what you did* - is either a **fused relative construction** or an **open interrogative**.

Consider sentence #3

> **What happened** is terrible.

The bold part - *what happened* - is either a **fused relative construction** or an **open interrogative**.

Consider sentence #1

> **How you say that** is funny.

The bold part - *how you say that* - is an open interrogative, not a fused relative clause.

A fused relative construction can never occur in extraposition construction. But an open interrogative can.

The following sentences are correct -

> It's possible that out team might win.

Here *that* is a subordinator and it introduces a subordinate clause to complete the meaning.

> It's I who did it.

In this sentence *who did it* is a relative construction and *who* a relativizer. The relative construction is adding some information about its antecedent - *I*.